# Different default behaviors of skipping empty buckets in timeseries queries by Druid native query and Druid SQL

Tags: apache-superset, druid, pydruid

According to the [document](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/timeseriesquery.html)  of Apache Druid about **native query**

> Timeseries queries normally fill empty interior time buckets with zeroes.
> For example, if you issue a "day" granularity timeseries query for the interval 2012-01-01/2012-01-04, and no data exists for 2012-01-02, you will receive:

```json
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2012-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "result": { "sample_name1": <some_value> }
  },
  {
   "timestamp": "2012-01-02T00:00:00.000Z",
   "result": { "sample_name1": 0 }
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2012-01-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    "result": { "sample_name1": <some_value> }
  }
]
```

This could be controlled by the value of context flag "skipEmptyBuckets", and the default value is `false` (do not skip the empty bucket by zero-filling).

However, when querying timeseries data with **Druid SQL**, the default behavior is to skip all empty buckets. I have to set query context explicitly to get the results I want.

```
  "context": {
    "skipEmptyBuckets": true
  }
```

This troubles me a lot because I need zero-filling to show all buckets in Apache Superset's timeseries charts. But there's no way to set the query context.

As far as I know, the SQL statement internally is translated to native query, so why is the inconsistency?